# How to write with pointers from index

Tags: c, arrays

Im new to c language. I am wondering how to write my code(which is with indexes) with pointers. If i understand right then changes needs only for "if" and when determinating an array. Am i right?

```
int poz_ind(int masivs[row][col], int r, int c,int rinda)
{
    rinda=-1;
    int i,j;


    for(i=0; i<r; i++)
    {
        fail=0;

        for(j=0; j<c; j++)
        {
            if(masivs[i][j]<=0)
            {
                fail=1;
                break;
            }
        }

        if(fail==0)
        {
            rinda=(i);
            break;
        }
    }

    if (rinda>-1)
    {
        rinda++;
    }
    else
    {
        rinda=0 ;
    }

    printf("Pirma rinda ar tikai pozitiviem elementiem ir rinda Nr:  %d\n",rinda);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`a[b]` is identical to `*(a + b)`.  From C11, **6.5.2.1 Array subscripting**, paragraph 2:

> The definition of the subscript operator **`[]`** is that **`E1[E2]`** is identical to **`(*((E1)+(E2)))`**

So in your case, `masivs[i][j]` is equivalent to `*(*(masivs + i) + j)`.

I can't for the life of me imagine why you'd choose the latter, though.

Comment: The question takes quite a bit of deciphering, but my guess is the OP wants to switch to a pointer that is incremented each iteration.

Comment: OP should probably write his question to say that, then.

Comment: if i write (masivs[i][j]<=0) like this(*(*(masivs + i) + j)<=0).
Then error is invalid type argument of `unary *'

Answer (score 1):

I won't rewrite the whole thing, but the reason to convert to pointers is speed when the optimizer isn't doing that.  The simplest approach adheres to the row structure of the matrix.  Only the inner loop makes sense to "pointerize", but I'll do both in case the 2D example is helpful to someone:

```
int[col] *prow, *plastrow; /* current row and (last+1) row pointers */
int rinda = -1;            /* row number with first negative entry */

for (prow=masivs, plastrow=prow+r; prow<plastrow; ++prow)
{
    int *pval, *plast;
    int fail = 0;
    for (pval = *prow, plast=pval+c; pval<plast; ++pval)
    {
        fail = (*prow < 0);
        if (fail) break;
    }
    if (!fail)
    {
        rinda = prow - masivs;
        break;
    }
}
```

Now you have the results that you wanted: `rinda` is -1 if every row has a negative entry, or the index of the first row found with no negative entries.  You add one afterward, but I'll leave that to you.

The less simple way involves treating the array as a single int[row*col] array, and on second thought I won't go into that because it's really only good to use of r==row and c==col.

You have another problem that needs attention.  You are using the argument variable `rinda` as a local variable, and it looks like you intend that value to be returned to the caller.  C passes non-array data by value, so the name `rinda` refers to a copy of caller's argument value that will be discarded as soon as the function returns. Returning a result using an argument requires a more normal use of pointers.  Try:

```
int poz_ind(int masivs[row][col], int r, int c,int *prinda)
{
     int  rinda = -1; /* as in the above snippet */
```

...then at the end, when you've calculated the final correct value of rinda:

```
    *prinda = rinda;
```

The call will need to call `poz_ind(masivs, r, c, &rinda)` to get the value stored in caller's variable named `rinda`.  It would be simpler to remove the `rinda` argument entirely and return the found value as a function result, since you don't seem to be returning anything.

My apologies for a long response if this last bit was what you were really trying to convert to pointers.